# Android phone extension numbers

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

ANdroid 5.0.2 - Several contacts with same company phone # but different extensions. But it only keeps one extension. All the rest ignore my edit in which I add the extension #, even though it says it's saving it.
Also only shows that ONE contact every time I get a call from that company.

Answer (score 0):

Open the dialer app and enter the number that you want to call.
Add a "pause" if you'll be entering the extension as soon as the line picks up. If the number you are calling allows you to enter the extension immediately after picking up, the "pause" function will automatically enter the extension after waiting a moment:
Press and hold the * button to add a space, a comma (,) and a space then add the extension # to the end of the number. This symbol indicates a two-second pause before the extension will be dialed. If pressing and holding the * button does not work, tap the (⋮) button next to the number and select "Add pause." If that doesn't work either, tap the number field to open your on-screen keyboard, then type a comma.
You can add multiple commas to wait longer. This may be useful for phone systems that have a delay before you can enter the extension.
On Windows phones, you'll need to type the comma in another app, copy it, then paste it to the end of the number.

OR

Add a "wait" if the extension can only be dialed after the whole menu plays. Some extensions cannot be entered until the entire automated menu service plays, or until a certain option is selected. The "wait" function will display the extension on your screen and you'll indicate when it should be entered.
Press and hold the # button to add a semicolon (;) to the end of the number. This symbol indicates a "wait," and the subsequent extension will not be dialed until you say so.
If you're using a Windows phone, you'll need to add a "w" instead of a ";". This will need to be copied and pasted from another app that allows you to type.[1]